# trouble with inserting php form data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

i have trouble inserting my with php into one table of mysql, i can insert in any other table but this one here is my code (is a test code)

This is the formulario.php code

```
    <form action="opformulario.php" method="POST">
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" /> 
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="correo" />  
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre2" placeholder="Nombre" /> 
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="apellido2" placeholder="apellido" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="date" name="apellido3" placeholder="apellido" />

        <input type="submit" value="aceptar" />
```

and this is the op formulario code

```
include("conexion.php"); 

     $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
     $correo = $_POST['correo'];
     $nombre2 = $_POST['nombre2'];
     $apellido2 = $_POST['apellido2'];
     $apellido3 = $_POST['apellido3'];

     $FechaMySQL = implode( '-', array_reverse( explode( '/', $apellido3 ) ) ) ;



$query = " INSERT INTO cliente (nom_raz,nom_com,tel_cli,cel_cli,email_cli,fecha_reg) VALUES('$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$nombre2','$apellido2','$FechaMySQL')";

     $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

     if ($resultado){
        echo "Succesfull";

     }
     else{
        echo "Error:<br />".mysql_error(); 
     }
```

this is the table in  which i am trying to insert
[Mysql 'cliente' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaxpB.png)

Comment: There are no values in your inputs. Have you tried using `print_r($_POST)` to see what data it holds? Try to change `<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />` to `<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="yourValue" />`

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com - Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections, otherwise your DB can be hacked in a few seconds.

Comment: do not trust user input.

Comment: Are you using `MYSQLI_` or `PDO`.

Comment: I dont know wich was the problem, but it solved when i create another table and delete the rfc_cli foreign key